# How to output all results from a formula as a list in a cell (Need to apply this down a column)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=IFS($A2="apple", "Apple",$B2="Carrot", "Carrot",$C2<>"Correct", "Error")
```

Is there a way to output every result in a row cell as a list? I want to be able to apply this down a column so each row-wise cell should have a different result given the row-wise reference

Example of OUTPUT:(each row is supposed to be a row-wise cell)

```
Apple, Carrot, Error
Carrot
Error
Apple, Error
```

Comment: you can just drag the cell down and the `2` should change to the row automatically.

Comment: yes but currently I'm only able to get one result, i would like it to display each result

Answer (score 0):

`IFS` is not the correct formula for this.  You will want to concatenate multiple ifs:

```
=MID(IF(A2="Apple",", Apple","")&IF(B2="Carrot",", Carrot","")&IF(C2<>"Correct",", Error",""),3,9999)
```

[image]

Or one can use TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,CHOOSE({1,2,3},IF(A2="Apple","Apple",""),IF(B2="Carrot","Carrot",""),IF(C2<>"Correct","Error","")))
```

[image]

either way, this requires separate `IF` statements.